# Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I have this small app with Firebase and i'm implementing CRUD operations. The issue comes when I have to delete a post. I get this error: `Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path`

Here is the service code:

```
createReview(review) {
  return this.db.list('/reviews').push(review)
}

getReviews(){
  return this.db.list('/reviews');
}

deleteReview(id:any){
  console.log(id)
  this.db.object('/reviews/' + id).remove();
}
```

Component TS

```
 delete(review) {
    console.log(review)
    this.movieService.deleteReview(review)
  }
```

HTML

```
  <div *ngIf="userReviews">
  <ul class="list-group" style="color:black" *ngFor="let r of userReviews">

    <li class="list-group-item">
     <p  class="font-weight-bold text-left">{{r.movie}}</p>
      <div class="img-wrapper">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ r.poster }}" alt="{{ r.poster }}" />
    </div>
      <br>
      <p  class="font-weight-bold text-left"> {{r.review}}</p>

      <span  class="bottom font-weight-bold text-left">by </span><span  class="font-italic">{{r.author}} </span>
      <button (click)="delete(r)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried hundreds of diferent aproaches, saw tutorials (got even more confused) and nothing. Can someone explain me how this works? Thank You

@Frank van Puffelen, this is the exported JSON from the firebase collection:

```
{
  "reviews" : {
    "-M1R0vU4PksYuf_0TiKc" : {
      "author" : "murphy",
      "movie" : "Rambo",
      "poster" : "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTI5Mjg1MzM4NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTAyNzUzMw@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
      "review" : "Arrow and bow"
    },
    "-M1R1xTntiR-qc4A6huw" : {
      "author" : "murphy",
      "movie" : "Sub Zero",
      "poster" : "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTI3MzE3MjUzN15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTcyMjEzMQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg",
      "review" : "must be chilli"
    }
  },
```

EDIT: the package.JSON @Frank van Puffelen

```
{
  "name": "MoviesDB",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.4.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.1.0",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^3.0.1",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.5.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.27",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.12.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.4",
    "angular-jwt": "^0.1.11",
    "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "firebase": "^7.9.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.8.1",
    "ng-starrating": "^1.0.11",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "ngx-embed-video": "^1.0.4",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "simple-oauth2": "^3.1.0",
    "source-map": "^0.7.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.801.3",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Frank van Puffelen
snapshotChances() was the solution. This methods returns the id from the node to delete in firebase. So, in the service, I get the reviews like this:

```
getReviews() {
    return this.db.list('/reviews').snapshotChanges();
  }
```

And the HTML should be

```
 <button (click)="delete(r.key)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
```

And back in the service, the delete method:

```
deleteReview(id: any) {
    console.log(id)
    this.db.object('reviews/' + id).remove();
  }
```

Comment: Good to hear that you found the solution!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be changing the meaning of `p` from `post` to an `id`. Assuming that each `post` has an `id` property, you probably want:

```
delete(post) {
  this.postService.deletePost(post.id)
}
```

Comment: it doesnt thwo error but the post is still the @Frank  van Puffelen

Comment: and if I log the id on the service, it comes undefined, so that's why nothing happends

Comment: do I need to fetch the uid?

Comment: I have no idea why you'd need to fetch a UID here. Does the first line of my answer make sense? You seem to be interpreting `post` as an `id`, which won't work. My code is just a guess of how you might fix that, but the implicit conversion is almost certain.

Comment: im sorry, yes I get it but i cant make it work, or i get the error or i get undefined

Comment: can you post waht might you think is the correct answer @Frank van Puffelen? Thank you

Comment: I already posted what I think. If that's not it and doesn't help, I'm out of options based on what you posted so far. You might want to add an example of the JSON you're showing (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: The problem is still the same, you're passing a `post` to `deletePost`, and then pretend that it's an ID. To delete a node, you need to pass its key/ID, i.e. `"-M1R1xTntiR-qc4A6huw"`.

Comment: I have a feeling you're looking for https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#snapshotchanges and https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1982, but I'm having a hard time finding the docs for the version of AngularFire you're using.

Comment: yes, I want to delete the node as I create it, ill post my my package JSON